# How do I select a range and change font color of specific words in Outlook web add-ins

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

In Outlook web add-in, I want to select text from email body, keep it as tracked object and then apply styling on it like we do in Word web add-in. In the Word, I do it the following way:

```
 //used to store current selected range 
var selection=null;

$scope.getSelectedText = function () {
     Word.run(function (context) {
            if (selection) {
                context.trackedObjects.remove(selection);
            }
            selection = context.document.getSelection();
            context.trackedObjects.add(selection);
            context.load(selection, 'text');
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    if (!selection.text) {
                        systemService.errorHandler("Please select any text from the document");
                        return false;
                    }
                }).then(context.sync);
        })
         .catch(systemService.errorHandler);
    };

//highlight Words in the selected range or body
   $scope.highlightWords = function (item) {

    var color = systemService.getColor(item.gradeText);
    var filteredWords = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("List")) || [];
    var promise = new OfficeExtension.Promise(function (resolve, reject) { resolve(null); });

    Word.run(function (context) {
        var selectedRange = (selection) ? selection : context.document.body;
        selectedRange.load('text');
        return context.sync().then(function () {

            if (selectedRange.text == "") {
                systemService.showNotification("Alert:", "No text found in the document!");
                return;
            }

            filteredWords.forEach(function (word) {
                promise = promise.then(function () {
                    return highlightRange(word, color);
                })
            });
        });

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}

function highlightRange(word, color) {
    return Word.run(selection, function (context) {
        var range = (selection) ? selection : context.document.body;
        var searchResults = null;
        searchResults = range.search(word, { ignorePunct: true, matchCase: false, matchWholeWord: true });

        searchResults.load('font');
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
                searchResults.items[i].font.color = color;
                searchResults.items[i].font.bold = true;
            }
        }).then(context.sync());

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
//highlight Words in the selected range or body
```

I have tried multiple ways to do but there is a problem while keeping track of the selected object. In Word, we can save the range and manipulate it overtime as needed, but in Outlook, the user have to keep the content selected in order to perform operation on it (like changing font color etc.). Also, do we have any font property available for outlook web add-ins like Word?

Comment: Hi, have you tried using getSelectedDataAsync to get the selected text and then replace/change it with specified coloured version of it? Note that you can use the coercionType.html to insert a html content. I am not sure what you mean by tracking the selected object. Maybe you can use setSelectedDataAsync to change content of the selected state.You can read more about the set apis here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#setselecteddataasync-data--options--callback-

Comment: In Word Add-in we have tracked objects, in which we can save different type of objects  such as Range object to use it later in another context.In Word add-in, I am using tracked range object to change style of the selected text like changing font color within the context without replacing the whole text, as mentioned in the function highlighRange(). I am also seeking the same functionality in outlook but it replaces the whole text instead of changing style within a context like Word. Also the user needs to keep the text selected to make setSelectedDataAsync work properly. Please guide

Comment: And yes, I have tried getSelectedDataAsync and setSelectedDataAsync methods. First of all, to use setSelectedDataAsync the user have to keep the content selected otherwise the content is inserted at the current cursor position which is not suitable. Secondly, I wasn't able to find Range object to apply font styles on it, I have to find and replace every word occurrence with the HTML having CSS applied on it e.g: if I want to change font color of all the occurrences of "pet" in the text I would replace it with <span style="color:red;">pet</span>

Comment: Unfortunately OWA doesn't support Range objects like Word. Currently the feature Range objects, as you suggested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.