# Outlook / Word Add-in: How to highlight a part of the text (range)

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-store, word-web-addins

Is there an Outlook/Word add-in api to highlight a section of the text, without really modifying the underlying html of the email or the Word document? The purpose is to notify the user about a relevant section in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the feature to highlight the part of text without updating the html is not a part of the Outlook Office.js API set. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.
You can check [contextual add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/contextual-outlook-add-ins) which highlights the text on which Add-ins is applicable. Check if it can be used for your usecase?

Comment: Another option is to have an API that simulates a user selection of a range. Do you have a "selectRange" api?

Comment: Unfortunately Outlook does not support selectRange api currently. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305382/how-do-i-select-a-range-and-change-font-color-of-specific-words-in-outlook-web-a) for more info.

Comment: But I see that add-ins do that, for example the Grammarly addin, highlights a word - what API does it use to achieve that goal? I see that it adds the class Selected to a word. Is there an API to add a class to range?

Comment: For Outlook, Grammarly is a COM Add-in and not a web Add-in.

Comment: @ Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT no, the Grammarly add-in for Word (the online version at https://onedrive.live.com/ ), and other company add-in, are able to select a text. How?

Comment: Outlook and Word have different addin APIs. Are you trying to build an Outlook addin or a Word addin? Outlook addin currently does not support "selectRange" api but you can always request for a feature on our user-voice page.